# AspNetCore.Owin equivalent to .netFramework Owin's WebApp.Start

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, owin, desktop-application

Anyone know of the rough equivalent for the following .netFramework Owin code?  It is currently being used to host a web interface on a WPF desktop application.

```
_server = WebApp.Start(hostingUrl.AbsoluteUri, ServerConfiguration);


private void ServerConfiguration(IAppBuilder builder)
{
  var config = new HttpConfiguration();
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "API Default",
            "{controller}/{clientId}",
            new { controller = "Callback", clientId = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

  var services = new ServiceCollection();
  services.AddSingleton<IFHIRWebhookClient>(this);
  services.AddTransient<CallbackController>();
  services.AddSingleton(_logger);
  services.AddSingleton<ISubscriptionManager>(_subscriptionManager);
  services.AddSingleton(_configuration);
  services.AddSingleton<IRSAKeyReader, RSAKeyReader>();

  if (_configuration.AdditionalControllers != null && _configuration.AdditionalControllers.Any())
  {
    foreach (var controllerType in _configuration.AdditionalControllers)
    {
      services.AddTransient(controllerType);
    }
  }

  var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

  var resolver = new DependencyResolver(serviceProvider);
  config.DependencyResolver = resolver;

  builder.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

The aspNetCore.Owin api does not have WebApp or IAppBuilder.  Is there still a way to start up an Owin webhost without going through ASP middleware?

Comment: Do you mean you want to start the web app inside the WPF desktop application? Do you mean you want to directly start the asp.net core application during WPF desktop application started ?

Comment: We have a .net framework WPF desktop application that starts up an embedded owin self host and we're migrating to .net6.  Owin for .netCore is completely different and we're struggling to figure out how to do a selfHost within a desktop application with it.

The selfHost needs to stay embedded in the desktop application.